# 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named nltk.metrics' on 'import nltk'

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, nltk, modulenotfounderror

I am working on Ubuntu and installed NLTK via apt-get for Python 3.6.
Here's my problem:

---

```
>>> import nltk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/wizard/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 128, in <module>
    from nltk.collocations import *
  File "/wizard/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/collocations.py", line 39, in <module>
    from nltk.metrics import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk.metrics'
```

I am a beginner on Ubuntu so I don't know how to solve this. I assume that the metrics module didn't get installed with the rest?

Answer (score 0):

Python librairies shouldn't be installed with `apt-get` but with `pip`.

In your case, you should install it with `pip install nltk`.
If you are new to Python and does not know about the package managing module Pip, check [this website](https://realpython.com/what-is-pip/).

I advice you to use virtual environments aswell when working with Python, check info [here](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#:%7E:text=virtualenv%20is%20used%20to%20manage,can%20install%20virtualenv%20using%20pip.).

Comment: I am working on a server and was advised to use apt-get, instead of locally installing with pip which I did before (with the same result)

Comment: Sorry but I do not know the answer then. I see no reason why `pip install nltk` produce any error. All I can guess is that you have environments or paths problems and not installing/or looking at the right place.